# Rmarkdown Retain .tex file

Tags: r, r-markdown, tex

In R, when compiling a markdown document using `rmarkdown::render(...)`, how can I retain the intermediate `.tex` file that is produced from knitting.

I have tried setting the `clean=FALSE` argument, but this retains the figures, not the final tex file or auxiliary files, which I need to inspect for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify it in your YML header with:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---
```

More options [on the rmarkdown site](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#keeping_intermediate_tex).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with bookdown?

Comment: not so familiar myself with bookdown