# Can I strike out text in an equation in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, equation

I have an equation that I wrote in r-markdown as follows

```
$$ 2 \frac{meter}{day} * 3 ~ days $$
```

[image: base equation]

I'd like to show that the `days` cancel by striking them out. You can strike out text in r-markdown normally by `~~surrounding the text in tildaes~~`

However, the tildae in the expression seems to only insert spaces.

`$$ 2 \frac{meter}{~~day~~} * 3 ~ ~~days~~ $$`

[image: tildae]

I also tried as one might in latex

`$$ 2 \frac{meter}{sout{day}} * 3 ~ days $$`

But this doesn't seem to work either.

[image: souteqn]

Are there any options for striking out bits of equation that work in r-markdown equations?

Comment: You're missing a backslash for `\sout`

Answer (score 3):

For PDF output you can use the LaTeX style `cancel`:

```
---
header-includes: \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
output: pdf_document
---

$$ 2 \frac{\text{meter}}{\cancel{\text{day}}} * 3 ~ \cancel{\text{days}} $$
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the usage of `\text` is unrelated to your question and only used for typographical reasons.

Unfortunately this does not work with HTML output.

Comment: When I add the header you have suggested on the header of the markdown document it stops the stops the creation of the pdf with the following error message ... ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \cancel

Comment: @TCS Does the minimal example that I posted work for you? Does your TeX system have the `cancel.sty` installed?

Comment: @Ralph It generates the error message that I mentioned above. I am running markdown using RStudio on a Mac and my tex live utility includes the cancel package.

Comment: @TCS Please update the test document to keep the TeX file (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37702315/8416610) and check that the resulting TeX file contains `\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}`.

Comment: @Ralph I looked at the TeX file and its does not contain the package. Can you please help/tell me on how to add it?

Comment: @TCS The `header-includes` YAML header should take care of that. Very odd. As an alternative you can write that line into a file and include it via `includes`, c.f. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#includes-1.

Comment: @Ralph Adding the line \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel} in the file preamble.tex did this for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have `\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}` listed in `header-includes` but I had to add additionally `$$\require{cancel} ... $$` in the equation to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

For HTML, add at the beginning of the markdown,

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
  MathJax.Hub.Insert(MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.macros,{
    cancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
    bcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
    xcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
    cancelto: ["Extension","cancel"]
  });
});
</script>
```

and then

```
$$2 \frac{\text{meter}}{\cancel{\text{day}}} * 3 ~ \cancel{\text{days}}$$
```

will work

[image]

Comment: I am using markdown to write a book and one of my chapters has an equation where I am using strike through font. When you say add the script at the beginning of the markdown do you mean to add this at the top of the relevant chapter? I tried it and it does not work. Thanks