# How to export R Notebook to LaTex (.tex)?

Tags: r, rstudio, tex

In **Jupyter Notebook** or **JupyterLab**, I have option to save as **LaTex** (**.tex**) which is very useful in case I want to edit the file. In **RStudio**, with **Knit**, we can export **R Notebook** to beautiful Word or PDF documents.

[image]

I would like to ask how to export **R Notebook** to LaTex (**.tex**). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37701995/680068 ?

Comment: Thank you @zx8754, it's actually a duplicate and the other thread solves my question. Please mark it as duplicate.