# ggplot: how to space plots in grid.arrange when using coord_fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2

Notice this is different from other questions because I use `coord_fixed()` which changes the spacing.

Here's my minimal working example:

**WITH COORD FIXED**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
x = runif(100)
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=x, y=x)) + geom_line(aes(x, y)) + theme_minimal() + coord_fixed()
grid.arrange(p, p, p, p, ncol=2)
```

[image]

**WITHOUT COORD FIXED**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
x = runif(100)
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=x, y=x)) + geom_line(aes(x, y)) + theme_minimal()
grid.arrange(p, p, p, p, ncol=2)
```

[image]

**QUESTION**
How can I make the first plot look like the second, just with fixed coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is using `patchwork`.

```
library(patchwork)

p + p + p + p
```

> The claim to fame of patchwork is mainly two things: A very intuitive API, and a layout engine that promises to keep your plots aligned no matter how complex a layout you concoct.

You can check this [post](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2019/patch-it-up-and-send-it-out/) about `patchwork`. The author is the main maintainer o `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2):

I also like the patchwork package, but let's stick to gridExtra. I think you may have looked at the RStudio viewer? It gives sometimes quite weird results.

If you (what I assume you will do in the end) create a device (with or without specific dimensions), at least on my machine this effect does not happen.

```
dev.new(width = 5, height = 4, noRStudioGD = TRUE)
grid.arrange(p, p, p, p, ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I had no idea there was a thing called device to be fair.. I'll look into it thank you!

Comment: @Euler_Salter check https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/Devices.html. A device is basically what you're drawing into, (and you need it to save figures). If you save as pdf, you create a pdf device first. This also happens with functions like ggsave, but less explicitely.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the Rstudio viewer pane is kind of lousy to show you what you actually get in the end. I guess that's because it can be resized in any dimensions and they kind of create a device "within" as a kind of viewport (I am not sure about that though). I control figure layouts in the device I want the figures in - usually pdf in my case. (and I always explicitly define the dimensions!)

Comment: thank you so much!! I need to save images to go on a Latex document (for a paper possibly). Do you have any suggestion about which device to use?

Comment: @Euler_Salter check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890215/getting-r-plots-into-latex. I guess it also depnds how you create your latex in the end. I am currently not yet using latex (but this will change), but am using rmarkdown (knitr) quite a lot - it can also produce pdf via latex - and you can get the tex files "for free" whilst knitting the document https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701995/rmarkdown-retain-tex-file