# Bookdown package for R, retain LaTeX file in render_book(..., pdf_book())

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I compile my .Rmd files using

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", bookdown::pdf_book())
```

How do I ensure the intermediate LaTeX file is retained and not cleaned up?

I am aware of [Rmarkdown Retain .tex file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37701995/452096), but for some reason, editing my YAML files does not keep the LaTeX file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a parameter `keep_tex = TRUE` in the `pdf_book()` command:

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", bookdown::pdf_book(keep_tex=TRUE))
```

After this, there will be a file `_main.tex` in the `_book` directory.